# How did Jim Rockford compensate Angel?

Tags: character, rockford-files

In *The Rockford Files*, Jim Rockford often tapped his friend Angel to play a part in a con.

How did he compensate Angel for his work? What incentive did Angel have to help Jim?

Comment: Jim charges “two hundred a day plus expenses”.  Presumably Angel is an expense.